# App crash using App Transport Security in iOS9

Tags: ios9, xcode7, app-transport-security

I have upgraded Xcode to Xcode 7 and included App Transport Security(ATS) feature in `pList`. Currently I have disabled this feature by assigning `YES` to `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`. Now app is running fine on simulator. However, when I release Adhoc development build and installed it on device. It crashes whenever any `API` is called.

[image]

Below is the image for crash details:
[image]

Comment: I am facing the same problem.

Comment: have you checked your `bit code` under Build settings? it should be `no` i think.

Comment: @Oyeoj Yes, Enable bitCode is set to NO

Comment: let me clarify that again: NSAppTransportSecurity[Dictionary] > NSAllowsArbitraryLoads[Bool] == YES in your .plist?

Comment: @AshishKakkad, mine run at first then crash at second build. weird right?

Comment: @Oyeoj: I have added screen shot of pList above.

Comment: Please also have a look at the image for crash details above.

Comment: @AshishKakkad In Xcode, Windows>Devices and by running the ADHOC build to attached device.

Comment: Please read following link. Might be useful: http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

Answer (score 0):

I have not started working on Captain OS but found below link for ATS that might be helpful

[Configuring App Transport Security](http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/)

Might be useful.